# Why does my date output have "STD" as the time zone?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, date, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run `date` on my Ubuntu under WSL, it prints:

```
Wed May 15 19:33:37 STD 2019
```

Why does this have the string `STD` in it? I can't find a timezone online with the abbreviation STD (for example [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)) and googling 'date std' gave me unexpected results.

Comment: What does `echo $TZ` output?

Comment: (`# TZ=STDBAR date` => 
`Wed May 15 09:54:47 STDBAR 2019`)

Comment: My `$TZ` is empty, which may be what is causing it. It's strange that `TZ=ZZ date` has no timezone but `TZ=STDBAR date` has the timezone `STDBAR`, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130880/8239155

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Jesse_b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237982/jesse-b) for finding this [Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130880/4957508):

> **TL;DR** WSL Dynamically generates a fake timezone info file at `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Msft/localtime` that in hard linked to `/etc/localtime`. The Msft file uses the made up names `DST` or `STD`, and they stand for no specific timezone.
>
> ---
>
> What is actually going on is WSL attempts to match your Windows timezone in Linux. This is a non-trivial mapping, as seen [here](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/zone_tzid.html) ([discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967903/linux-windows-timezone-mapping)). So rather than trying to hit a constantly moving target, what I believe WSL does is use the [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the Windows Timezone info, and based off of that information, it dynamically generates a [timezone info file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html).
>
> I believe that `wslhost` (specifically code in `C:\Windows\System32\lxss\LxssManager.dll`) does this inspection on your current timezone in Windows, and writes to the the `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Msft/localtime` file. This is why when the timezone in Windows changes, you see the affect in an already running WSL instantly. But since there is no perfect mapping from Windows timezones to Linux or POSIX timezones, `wslhost` probably just *wings* the name, and that's where the DST comes into play.
>
> *Update:* Actually, I think it just says "DST" if you are in Daylight Saving Zone timezone, and "STD" for non DST timezone (Standard I assume).
>
> So the answer to "What timezone does DST stand for" is none, and any Linux program that will attempt to match `/etc/localtime` to a timezone file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` (via readlink or just searching), will only every get "Msft/localtime" as an answer. A "Technically accurate, but totally useless" answer.

---

The Windows 19H1 (1903) update, scheduled for final release in May 2019, [resolves](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3747#issuecomment-461947865) this issue and WSL distributions will report a conventional time zone where possible:

[image: Windows 1903 WSL showing proper time zone]

Until the final public release, the new version [is already available through the Windows Insider programme](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced), so if you have an active issue caused by the zone tag it is possible to work around it. You don't need to do anything to activate it or have the new time zone applied.